# How to change firefox profile preference after defining webdriver using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, user-agent, firefox-profile

How to change profile preference after defining driver?

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

After some code need to set useragent

```
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", ua)
```

How to set it without defining new driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current implementation of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) once you configure the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) with specific *Capabilities* and initialize the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) session to open a *Browsing Context*, you cannot change the capabilities runtime. Even if you are able to retrieve the runtime capabilities still you won't be able to change them back.

So, in-order to change the *Firefox User Preference* you have to initiate a new *WebDriver* session.

> **Note**:However, you can change the [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) for Firefox on each run and you can find a relevant discussion in [How to change user agent for Firefox webdriver in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271599/how-to-change-user-agent-for-firefox-webdriver-in-python/54271641#54271641)

---

### Reference

Here is @JimEvans [clear and concise comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565426/how-to-change-firefox-web-driver-proxy-settings-in-runtime) (as of Oct 24 '13 at 13:02) related to proxy settings capability:

> When you set a proxy for any given driver, it is set only at the time WebDriver session is created; it cannot be changed at runtime. Even if you get the capabilities of the created session, you won't be able to change it. So the answer is, no, you must start a new session if you want to use different proxy settings.

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python and selenium: how to change Firefox's profile multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864667/python-and-selenium-how-to-change-firefoxs-profile-multiple-times/62865054#62865054)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it’s not possible but I found some workarounds explained in this article, not sure if those approaches are reliable though (or work at all): https://tarunlalwani.com/post/change-profile-settings-at-runtime-firefox-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this exactly what the `set_context()` method is for.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.8.0/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L224-L247

For example:

```
driver.set_context("chrome")
driver.execute_script("Services.prefs.setStringPref('intl.accept_languages', 'es-ES');")
driver.set_context("context")
```

Make sure you switch back to "context" or else you won't be able to continue.