# Mismatch in UserAgent initiating Firefox manually and using GeckoDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, user-agent, geckodriver

Why is not the useragent the same in both cases?

https://www.whatsmyua.info/ reports the following when I browse with usual Firefox:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0
```

However, browsing with geckodriver reports:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
```

Here's how I start browsing with geckodriver:

```
options=Options()
profile_path = '/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/x9zoqd7t.default-release/'
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
service = Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyua.info/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually accessing *Firefox* ***v97.0*** and accessing [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) ***v0.30.0*** initiated [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *Browsing Context*, either way I see the same [*User Agent*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70510724/7429447) as follows:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0
```

The most probhable reason for the mismatch is, you have 2 instances of *Firefox* browser installed.

The instance which you are accessing manually haven't been updated since it's previous version of ***96.0***, where as the instance installed at the location *`/home/myuser/.mozilla/firefox/`* haven't been updated since ***91.0***. Hence you observe the difference in the [*useragent*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54271641/7429447)

Comment: Your are right, I found another version installed! Btw, geckodriver doesn't present itself as headless or bot in the useragent. Is that normal?

Comment: @Rimfire I haven't looked into the specifics whether _geckodriver doesn't present itself as headless or bot in the useragent_. If you have a specific question feel free to raise it, I'd like to dig deeper to help you out.